# mysql 5.5 to mariadb 10.2.13: 4000% increase in execution time for select

Tags: mysql, select, mariadb

I am facing a performance issue that has manifested itself after a migration from mysql 5.5 to mariadb 10.2.13 . The sizing of both machines including configs is the same. We have noticed that a certain select statement suddenly takes ~20 secs to execute instead of 0.5 sec. The data is purely read from memory as there is zero read IO to be measured during execution. Changing the optimizer_switch on the mariadb to the settings of mysql5.5 did not change the execution plan.

The explain for the select on the mariadb looks as follows:
[image: 20 sec execution time]

The explain for the select on the mysql5.5 :

[image: 0.5 sec execution]

Select-Statement:

```
SELECT  acmh.OBJ_VERSION,acmh.peannr,acmh.pzsrnr,xuts.ptitle,
        acmh.pcategory,acmh.psalutatio,acmh.plastname,acmh.pfirstname,
        acmh.pcompanyna,syoq.paddress1,syoq.pzip,syoq.pcity,syoq.pphone1,
        syoq.pphone2,syoq.pphone3,syoq.pphone4,syoq.pemail,acmh.piscompany,
        xuts.id
    FROM  catalog1.tr_table_acmh acmh,catalog1.tr_table_syoq syoq,
        catalog1.tr_table_xuts xuts,catalog1.tr_table_wdvi link0,
        catalog1.tr_table_wdvi acl0
    WHERE  acmh.id=syoq.id
      AND  acmh.id=xuts.id
      AND  syoq.id=xuts.id
      AND  xuts.OBJ_TYPE IN (1557)
      AND ( (xuts.id=link0.pchild
       AND  link0.pparent='xkgrrslqkeaaaaendrxa'
       AND  link0.pname='folder')
       and  1 = 1 )
      AND  xuts.pvcurrent=1
      AND  (acl0.pchild=xuts.pacl
       AND  acl0.pparent='xkgrrswxbjaaaaaaabip'
       AND  acl0.pvalue>=20
           )
    order by acmh.plastname asc,
             acmh.pfirstname asc,
             acmh.pcompanyna asc
    LIMIT  10 OFFSET 0;
```

Is there any switch that im missing that could enforce a different behaviour on the mariadb?

Comment: Have you converted your tables to InnoDB? Please also show the query.

Comment: Added the select. All tables are innodb. I have transferred the data by doing a mysqldump and a mysql_upgrade afterwards (on the mariadb)

Comment: For starters, make sure you have run `ANALYZE` on all involved tables (you haven't mentioned that you've done it). Unlike MySQL/MariaDB with InnoDB 5.5, MariaDB 10.2 has InnoDB 5.7 which uses persistent statistics by default. It might be that the stored stat values, if any, differ heavily from the reality.

Comment: @elenst you're glorious, thank you, now it runs in 0.6 secs. I will read up on how analyze table works and add the answer if you dont want to add it yourself.

Comment: Sure, go for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the statistics for the query optimizer (ANALYZE TABLE on the 3 tables involved) fixed the issue in this case.

The new execution plan for the SELECT now looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

These may help performance:

```
 link0:  INDEX(pchild, pparent, pname)
 link0:  INDEX(pparent, pname, pchild)
 xuts:   INDEX(pvcurrent, OBJ_TYPE, id)
 acl0:   INDEX(pchild, pparent, pvalue)
```

You seem to have several tables that are 1:1; is this true?  If so, why?

What is the datatype of `id`?  It seems to be a strange length: 20.